# Formik checkbox with Semantic-UI styling

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, formik

Hi,

I've been trying to combine Semantic-UI (Semantic-UI React, to be specific) and Formik, but I keep running into problems. Currently I'm having a problem with checkboxes.

I'm trying to create a generic Formik-aware checkbox component with Semantic-UI styling. This is what I currently have:

```jsx
const Checkbox = ({ name, title, toggle, fitted, inline }, context) => {
    const { formik } = context;
    const error = formik.errors[name];
    const value = formik.values[name];

    return (
        <Form.Checkbox
            inline={inline}
            fitted={fitted}
            label={title || (fitted ? null : name)}
            name={name}
            toggle={toggle}
            checked={value ? true : false}
            onChange={(e, { name, checked }) => formik.setFieldValue(name, !!checked)}
            />
    );
};

Checkbox.contextTypes = { formik: PropTypes.object }
```

This kind of works. The only problem I'm currently having is with nested values. For example:

```jsx
<Checkbox name="sections.0.enabled"/>
```

My Checkbox implementation will use `formik.values["sections.0.enabled"]` as value, while a formik Field would correctly pick the value from `formik.values["sections"][0]["enabled"]`.

Is there a better way to do this, or should I just flatten the input values?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **lodash.get** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get) or simply use a function which does the exact same job:

```js
function get( object, keys, defaultVal ){
  keys = Array.isArray( keys )? keys : keys.split('.');
  object = object[keys[0]];
  if( object && keys.length>1 ){
    return get( object, keys.slice(1) );
  }
  return object === undefined? defaultVal : object;
}
```

Then,

```js
...
const error = get(formik.errors, name);
const value = get(formik.values, name);
...
```